# Angular Get from API succeeds but values are undefined

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I'm trying to get data from an API. The GET request seems to be successful because, when I display the GET result in the console view, I can see that I'm getting an array of the right size and with the correct values. The issue is that, when I try to read a single data from an array element, it is undefined.

```
export class Achat {
    constructor(
      public IDAchat_PK: number,
      public Date: Date,
      public Fournisseur: string,
      public FraisLivraison: string,
      public status: number
    ) {}
  }
```

```
export class DbService {

  /* Back end URL */
  public Back_End_Url = "https://localhost:7198/pokegong/";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public GetAchats(): Observable<Achat> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Achat>(this.Back_End_Url + "Achat");
  }
}
```

```
export class StockComponent implements OnInit {
  
  achats: Achat[] = [];

  constructor(private dbService: DbService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("app-stock is initializing");
    this.GetAchats();
  }

  GetAchats() {
    /* Get stock items from Back End and fill _stock_items*/
    return this.dbService.GetAchats().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.achats = data;
      console.log(this.achats[3])
      console.log(this.achats[3].Fournisseur)
    });
  } 
}
```

Upon execution of console.log(this.achats[3]), I can see in the console the text
{idAchat_PK: 4, date: '2022-10-05T00:00:00', fournisseur: 'VISTAPRINT', fraisLivraison: 6.19, status: 2}

However, upon execution of console.log(this.achats[3].Fournisseur), I get the 'undefined' value.

All my workaround was not successful. I really don't understand how I can be able to read a full JSON record, but not a single element within this record.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You got a mistake in your code. You reffered to `Fournisseur` instead of `fournisseur`...

JS is a case-sensitive language.

Comment: Thank you, it works ! I actually used the names programmed in the Back end but, in the JSON, some letters cases changed.

Answer (score 0):

The console log shows a **lowercase** fournisseur key. In your class you use a variable with a **uppercase** "F" (**F**ournisseur). So the value cannot be right converted.

I think `console.log(this.achats[3].fournisseur)` will work as well.

You can map the result, too like `const convertedResult = this.achats.map((data) => {return new Achat(.....);})`

Greetings, Flo